# Can't display DateField on form and initial on template with auto_now = True

Tags: python, django, django-models, datefield

model modelname:

```
    pubDate = models.DateField('pubDate', auto_now_add=True)

form field:

    class formname(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = modelname
            fields = ['pubDate']
```

error:

> Unknown field(s) (pubDate) specified for modelname

I want to display `pubDate` in template.

I try forms `exclude = []`.Then all fields display but `pubDate`.
I don't know why?

Comment: Why would you want to display empty non-editable field?

Comment: show non-editable field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: Show a model instance to template,contains pubDate.

Answer (score 0):

You need add attribute to you `pubDate` attr:

```
pubDate = models.DateField('pubDate', auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```